# Is mozzarella water safe for cats to drink?

Tags: cats, diet, drinking

One day when having dinner, my dad poured the water a fresh mozzarella comes packaged in inside a flower pot, and we noticed shortly after the cat jumping onto it and licking it.

Next time I had a mozzarella, I poured its water in the cat bowl and he started drinking it - and he seems to enjoy it a lot. He also enjoys bits of the mozzarella itself.

According to the label the mozzarella contains: milk, salt, rennet, probiotics.

As far as I know you are not supposed to give regular milk to a cat. What about the mozzarella water? Or mozzarella itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "mozzarella water" from the package might be one of two things, depending on brand:

- brine (contains lots of salt, essentially negating fluid intake)
- whey (contains lactose, leads to upset stomach and diarrhea)

Neither should really be given to a cat, but a small sip just to have a taste should not harm an adult cat. *Never give it to kittens.*

Mozzarella itself is typically high in fat and also contains lactose, so it shouldn't be given to a cat either. A small bit as a treat should not harm an adult cat, but again *never give it to a kitten.*

Comment: Note that brine shouldn't really be poured into flower pots either, the salt will accumulate in the pot over time, and kill most flowers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My cat is adult, regarding the mozzarella water I usually let him sip how much he feels like and then throw the rest away, and for mozzarella it's usually just a small piece or two as treat.